# Is there a way to get the response token of reCAPTCHA without submitting?

Tags: html, web-deployment, recaptcha, captcha

After setting up recaptcha to a html form (as follows) it will send the response token with the form submit. Is there a way to get the recaptcha response token (to the frontend) without submitting the form?

```html
 <form action="?" method="POST">
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
   <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

It’s server-side service and you need to call it to get a response.